# Are static variables inherited

Tags: java, inheritance, static, data-hiding

I have read at 1000's of locations that Static variables are not inherited. But then how this code works fine?

**Parent.java**

```
public class Parent {
        static String str = "Parent";
    }
```

**Child.java**

```
public class Child extends Parent {
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            System.out.println(Child.str);
        }
    }
```

This code prints "Parent".

Also read at few locations concept of data hiding.

**Parent.java**

```
public class Parent {
    static String str = "Parent";
}
```

**Child.java**

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    static String str = "Child";

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Child.str);
    }
}
```

Now the output is "Child".

So does this mean that **static variables are inherited but they follow the concept of data-hiding**?

Comment: Can you give any of the _"1000's of locations"_

Comment: @Hackerdarshi --> https://www.google.co.in/search?client=opera&q=are+static+variables+inherited+in+java&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please have a look into the documentation of oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#d5e12110

Static variables are inherited as long as they're are not hidden by another static variable with the same identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1 line compiles it all "Static variables are inherited as long as their are not hidden by another static variable with the same identifier."

Answer (score 38):

*"Inherited"* is not an ideal description of what is happening; a better way to describe it would be to say that static variables are *shared* among the subclasses of the base class.

All derived classes obtain access to static variables of their base classes. This includes protected variables, mirroring the situation with variables that are inherited.

The concept of hiding applies as well: when a class-specific variable `str` appears in the `Child` class, it hides the `str` variable of the parent class.

Note that the variable `str` of the base class does not become inaccessible: `Child` can still access it by fully qualifying with the name of `Parent` class.

Comment: In the example given how do we access it using the fully qualified parent name?

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly inheritance, its more like sharing having access to the static attribute of the class you are extending unless you are hiding it by declaring the same identifier in you subclass, note that in case of instance attribute  if you change the value of the inherited attribute it will be changed in the super instance  which was instantiated for your object but if there is another hierarchy which will be supposedly blind to your hierarchy it will not be affected.

In the case of static the parent attribute will be changed and any other hierarchy will take this effect too.

Answer (score 0):

inheritance is between parent class object and child class object (not class but objects) . class is not an actual thing but  template(structire only) and when you create a child class the teplate is just enlarged also having old structute(here, static method)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).